# Configuring KaTeX (code injection) in Circle.so

Tags: javascript, inject

I am building an online community for IB Math students and for that I plan to use [Circle.so](https://circle.so). Circle.so seems like a great option given its features (like code injection) and design.

One of the features that the forum tool (such as Circle) needs to have is the ability to render Math notation (LaTeX) or allow code injection so KaTeX or MathJax can be used. [KaTeX](https://katex.org/) seems to solve the problem. I am testing/trying to install KaTeX and I have the options to inject code in the head and as a javascript snippet (as shown in the image below).

[image]

I have zero programming skills, I wonder if anyone has done it or could help me accomplish that. For the head portion, I placed the following code (it didn't work).

```
<!-- The loading of KaTeX is deferred to speed up page rendering -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.6/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-ljao5I1l+8KYFXG7LNEA7DyaFvuvSCmedUf6Y6JI7LJqiu8q5dEivP2nDdFH31V4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- To automatically render math in text elements, include the auto-render extension: -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.6/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-+XBljXPPiv+OzfbB3cVmLHf4hdUFHlWNZN5spNQ7rmHTXpd7WvJum6fIACpNNfIR" crossorigin="anonymous"
    onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
```

KaTeX's documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX).

**Obs: Circle.so has the option to insert custom CSS (if that helps)**

Comment: Looks like maybe this should be migrated to https://webapps.stackexchange.com , not sure though.

Comment: From the screenshot you have provided, it looks like the second field (javascript) is for some inline code only, it states please exclude the ```<script>``` below the name of field. Therefore I think you should try and copy all of that js filed to head tag (filed above) this should include the scripts you want. Later on you test if they are loading by going to your website and opening the developers console in sources tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 2 part problem, one pretty easy the other a bit harder.

##### Problem 1

## Parsing KATEX

This is relatively easy,

We add the scripts and styles on the page and our custom script to select and render text.

> ### This can go under *Header code snippets*
>
> Notice: No `defer` attribute to make it load before JS code runs.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.6/dist/katex.css" integrity="sha384-jJFDzw6Rh7jzIumRp31oSKurBXlvFPBHbzi9KbVukp6ZNECGD4UKyhO5tJaJ1uHA" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.6/dist/katex.js" integrity="sha384-Xfbu6aqAjKdi+UhRmQROxVxvx/iT6irqZqIPGKTbtyjUVRkdg3aEiaxuMdfVqNyu" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And some JS to render KATEX strings.

```
katex.renderToString( katexText, {
  throwOnError: false
});
```

### Unresolved issues

##### We don't know...

1. which text to render Katex.
2. where to place the rendered text.

##### Problem 2

## How do users insert Katex

This is a challenging one coz we don't control the UI. However a workaround could be to use `Code` option from the toolbar.

[image]

[image]

However we don't want to parse and potentially break all code blocks, but only specific ones, for this we could add in a key word to trigger `katex` and keyword can just be `katex`. So to use katex, users would add a code block with `katex` on first line and our JS will take it from there.

> ### This can go under *Header code snippets*

```
<script id=''>
    // Find all `pre` tags
    document.querySelectorAll('.trix-content pre').forEach(function(el) {
        // Get text inside
        var text = el.innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
        // Do stuff if text starts with `latex`
        if (0 === text.indexOf('katex')) {
            var renderedKatex = katex.renderToString(
                text.replace('katex', ''),
                {throwOnError: false}
            );
            // Populate katex and additional markup for formatting
            el.outerHTML =
                '<span></span><section class="katex-wrap">' +
                renderedKatex + '</section>';
        }
    })
<script>
```

###### Before scripts

[image: Before scripts]

###### After scripts

[image: After scripts]

## Working snippet

```js
// Find all `pre` tags
document.querySelectorAll('.trix-content pre').forEach(function(el) {
  // Get text inside
  var text = el.innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
  // Do stuff if text starts with `latex`
  if (0 === text.indexOf('katex')) {
    var renderedKatex = katex.renderToString(text.replace('katex', ''), {
      throwOnError: false
    });
    // Populat katex and additional markup for formatting
    el.outerHTML = '<span></span><section class="katex-wrap">' + renderedKatex + '</section>';
  }
})
```

```css
.post__more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- THIS GOES IN HEAD CODE SNIPPETS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.6/dist/katex.css" integrity="sha384-jJFDzw6Rh7jzIumRp31oSKurBXlvFPBHbzi9KbVukp6ZNECGD4UKyhO5tJaJ1uHA" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.6/dist/katex.js" integrity="sha384-Xfbu6aqAjKdi+UhRmQROxVxvx/iT6irqZqIPGKTbtyjUVRkdg3aEiaxuMdfVqNyu" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h1>Typical circle.so markup</h1>

<h2>Main post content markup</h2>

<div class="post__body">
  <div class="post__inside trix-v2  expanded">
    <div class="react-trix-content fullscreen-preview-enabled">
      <div>
        <div class="trix-content">
          <pre>katex
c = \pm\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}</pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Comment post content markup</h2>

<div class="post__body" data-controller="post">
  <div class="post__inside">
    <div class="trix-content">
      <div>Ordinary code block,</div>
      <pre>const jsVar = 'mi secreto';</pre>
      <div>
        <br>Latex code block<br><br>
      </div>
      <pre>katex
e = mc^2</pre>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```